# Enabling "maximize" button using NWJS

Tags: javascript, html, desktop-application, nwjs

I'm developping a desktop app using NWJS. I have a problem when I try to maximize the window. The button appears disabled, so I can`t maximize the window, only let me closing and minimizing the window.

Thats my package.json:

```
{
"name": "APP",
"main": "index.html",
"icon": "icon.png",
"version": "0.0.1",
"window": {
    "title": "APP",
    "icon": "icon.png",
    "toolbar": false,
    "resizable": true,
    "frame": true,
    "fullscreen": false,
    "width": 1280,
    "height": 1024,
    "min_width": 360,
    "min_height": 640,
    "max_width": 1920,
    "max_height": 1080,
    "position": "center"
    }    
}
```

Anyone could help me? It was grateful. Thanks!

Comment: what plattform are you on? Maybe you should add a menu

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. The Solution is just remove the max_width and max_height. After removing these the maximise option will come. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When your app starts do something like this...

```
var MaxWin=require('nw.gui').Window.get();

MaxWin.setMaximumSize(0,screen.availHeight);
```

And later use a couple of icons or buttons to maximize/minimize like this...

```
<input type="button" onclick="MaxWin.minimize();" value="Minimize">

<input type="button" onclick="MaxWin.maximize();" value="Maximize">
```